# Переклад з англійської "defeat in detail"?

Tags: переклад

В англійській мові є спеціальний термін [”defeat in detail“](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defeat_in_detail) — тактика ведення бою, де військова сила намагається послідовно знищувати менші частини ворожої сили, а не всю ворожу силу цілком.

Чи існує в українській мові еквівалентний термін?

Comment: Шукаючи в E2U «[in detail](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=in+detail&highlight=on)», окрім очевидно невлучних («всебічно» і «докладно»), натрапив на «нароздріб». Хоча «перемога/поразка нароздріб» навряд є самозрозумілим словосполученням, але якщо з поясненнями (наприклад, якщо Ви маєте можливість самі визначати терміни на початку роботи і потім використовувати їх), то, тоже, підійде.

Comment: А сербохорватська Вікіпедія використовує «[počesni poraz](//sh.wikipedia.org/wiki/Počesni_poraz)», що, на мою думку, означає «[почастинна](//www.google.com/search?q=почастинний&tbm=bks) поразка» (а не «почесна»).

Comment: А росіяни [використовують](http://translate.academic.ru/defeat/en/ru/) «разгром по частям» («розгром по частинах»?).

Comment: @Sasha дуже дякую, візьму "нароздріб". Це, зрештою, художня література :) Просто контекст там "для цього є окремий військовий термін defeated in detail", тому хотілося усталеного терміну... На спроби перекладати з інших мов завжди реагую негативно (можливо навіть неадекватно) :) Але ну чесно, доки ви на інші не дивилися, був чудовий переклад "поразка/перемога нароздріб", а потім пішли кальки з різних мов... Це моя особиста думка :) Можливо хтось все ж таки знайде щось у якихось друкованих виданнях, але доки цього не станеться, перекладатиму всюди "нароздріб". Ще раз дякую.

Comment: Як щодо „Знищення нароздріб“?

Comment: @Follower, Ну от, тепер думати доведеться :) Ваш варіант теж подобається, наразі найбільше, але я ще поміркую...

Comment: Можливо це щось на кшталт рос. "Разделяй и властвуй"?

Comment: У методиках ефективного ведення бізнесу є вираз *«зʼїсти слона можна лише по частинах»*. Якщо контекст дозволяє, невеличка влучна метафора може стати у нагоді.

Answer (score -2):

Остаточно розбити, остаточно розгромити, повністю розбити/розгромити

Comment: Наскільки я розумію з тексту запитання, мова не про остаточність, а радше навпаки — про поступовість.

Comment: -1: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to back it with references to credible sources and/or academic research. Unbacked posts attract downvotes and disputes.

Comment: цей вираз має інше значення. Він описує саме перебіг розбиття/винищення.

Answer (score -2):

А також можна перекласти як "Знищити/ розбити вщент", "завдати нищівної поразки"[image]

Comment: Такий переклад буде ну дуже неточним. Перший з наведених на знімку перекладів просто поганий, гадаю, що перекладач полінувався знайти кращий. Третій не стосується запитання. А другий доводить те, що ваш переклад неточний.

Comment: @Yola, але все-таки вони доводять, що принаймні хтось принаймні в певних контекстах інтерпретує «in detail» як «completely» (навіть якщо помилково).

Comment: Яно Сергієнко, вибачте за безтактну пораду, але загалом (якщо немає значних причин робити по-іншому) краще висловлювати свою думку у вигляді однієї відповіді (за потреби редагуючи її посиланням «edit»), а не створювати по окремих відповідей від однієї людини на одне запитання.

Answer (score -5):

Якщо ввести це словосполучення у словник [Мультитран](https://www.multitran.ru/c/M.exe?l1=1&l2=2&s=defeat%20in%20detail), то отримаємо "разбивать по частям", тобто українською "розбивати по частинам". Також згідно до [СУМу](http://sum.in.ua/s/rozbyvaty) слово "розбивати" має значення "завдавати поразки кому-, чому-небудь, перемагати когось, щось у боротьбі, битві", тому воно буде тут доречним.

Comment: -1, годі переклади на українську через російську.

Comment: Наскільки я знаю, літературною українською «по» не сполучається з давальним відмінком (лише з місцевим або іноді знахідним). Тобто або «частинами», або «по частина**х**» (не «по частина**м**»).